# Drupal 7 custom main menu

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-7

I desperately need help. I am trying to customize main menu (only) in Drupal 7 so that it suits my blueprintcss needs. I tried to find the answer in the documentation, but there is no straightforward example for this, which makes it a bit difficult.

Basic requirement is to have other menus (navigation etc) not affected by the main menu styling.

My **page.tpl.php** includes this code:

```
<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
<div class="span-9" id="topmenu">
<?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
'links' => $main_menu,
'attributes' => array(
'id' => 'main-menu',
'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
),
)); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The output shows:

```
<div class="span-9" id="topmenu"> 
<ul id="main-menu" class="links inline clearfix">
 <li class="menu-151 first"><a href="/drupal/" title="">Home</a></li> 
 <li class="menu-152"><a href="/drupal/" title="">Contact Us</a></li> 
 <li class="menu-153 last"><a href="/drupal/" title="">About Us</a></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Whereas the desired output should be something like this:

```
<div class="span-9" id="topmenu">
 <div class="span-3 menu-151"><a href="/drupal/" title="">Home</a></div>
 <div class="span-3 menu-152"><a href="/drupal/" title="">Contact Us</a></div>
 <div class="span-3 menu-153 last"><a href="/drupal/" title="">About Us</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can override the theme function to modify the generated markup.

To achieve this :

1. Locate the theme function you are calling (shall be
   `theme_links__system_main_menu`).
2. Copy and paste the code of this function into a custom theme function (could
   be done in `phptemplate` or custom module)
3. Customise your theme function to use `divs` instead of `ul li`

See the offical Drupal documentation : [Overriding themable output](http://drupal.org/node/341628) Section "How to change HTML the Drupal way"